# How to track the source of link from where it was clicked?

Tags: html, click, tracking

I am trying to create a product which has supporting sites and application. I want to give special attributes in my web site, so that whenever a user clicks on site and reaches the application, I can get to  know that the user was diverted from the web site ?

It is a static site using jsut HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional query parameters in your link after '?'. For adding the details of the source add the parameter like 
http://yourdomain.com/sub-domain?ref=sourceWebSite.com